# Update UI before database to increase app perfomance?

Tags: ios, swift, database, performance, user-interface

I am developing my first app and it is in a quite well developed stage I would say.
Inside the app the user can upload items, which I store inside `Cloud-Firestore` and also `UserDefaults`.

**Current `addItem`-workflow:**

1. User presses `add-Button`
2. I upload item to `Cloud-Firestore`
3. wait till upload is finished
4. update UI and set `UserDefaults`.

I choose this approach as it is quite *safe*  in my opinion. I don't run into any troubles if *Step 2*  fails. However this heavily inpacts the app perfomance/user experience. Sometime if the `itemToUpload` is bigger the user has to wait several seconds till the item is actually added to the UI. (I am already using a `activityIndicator` so the user knows something is loading but no one likes to wait...)

So my question is: Is it safe to change *Step 2* with *Step 4* ? How do apps like Todoist, Wunderlist, etc. handle that? There I don't have to wait.

I don't think code is necessary for this question but let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocking user interaction and showing a loader for a long time is definitely not good for the app.

Break step4 into two sub-steps : 4a) Update UI 4b) set `UserDefaults`. Your flow should be -

• Update the UI as soon as user taps on `add-Button`

• Upload item to cloud-store in a background thread and listen to completion event

• If upload is success, update `UserDefaults`

• If upload fails, inform the user (toast/notification banner/alert) and maybe take user back to the screen from where upload transaction was initiated.

PS: You can also build a retry mechanism in case upload fails due to network errors.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, sounds like a reasonable safe approach and I will give it a try, thanks